# Login_validation() in CodeIgniter not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->login();
}

public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function members() 
{
    $this->load->view('members');
}

public function login_validation()

{
    $this->load->library('Form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        redirect('main/members');
    }
    else 
    { 
        echo 'not working';
    }
}
```

}

This is the login_validation function and this is the login form in the view:

```
<?php 

    echo form_open('main/login_validation');

    echo validation_errors();

    echo "<p>Email: ";
    echo form_input('email');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>Password: ";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit','Login');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();

?>
```

When I enter the email and password into the fields it returns "not working".

Also if I don't enter the email or password it also returns not working which means the library is unable to load I guess. I already double checked the documentation and everything seems to be right. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you removed index.php in your config file because you may need to use index.php in `form_open('index.php/main/login_validation');`

Comment: Yes removed it and i'm basically trying to follow a tutorial series on youtube, i did basically everything the same.

Comment: Have you load the form helper at your controller `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));` @Aman

Comment: @Astro Yes, they are already set in autoload and even tried putting this code in the function itself but same result., it probably has something to do with the rules cause the call to the fucntion is working or maybe the library isnt loading.

Comment: Strange, I have tested your code, and it's working...

Comment: I dont know, maybe im missing something else in the setup process of codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Before saying any thing i want to know , does any thing print or redirect to your desire uri? 
If Not
1. 
At first have to know the version of CI. If you are using CI 3.00 then you should check you Controller file name and class name (Both should need start with UPPERCASE).
2.Check your .htaccess.

Comment: it prints 'not working' which i put in the else statement to check, I am using CI 3 and yes the file is Main.php in the controller and the class name is also Main, I'll add the full controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing your function with given below :

```
 public function login_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo 'not working';
        }
        else 
        { 
            redirect('main/members');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Strange. what is the url of login page ?

Comment: localhost/views/login.php

Comment: No, i mean www.domain_name.com/main, what is you `domain name`

Comment: Also Are you running it as localhost/views/login.php ?

Comment: http://puu.sh/ktsuz/b08cb171e7.png this is how it looks im testing the code on my machine first since i dont have a webhost yet. and this after login http://puu.sh/ktsxq/69a13b305c.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90989/discussion-between-abhishek-sharma-and-aman).